# Is there a better way of creating an "abstract" linear search?

Tags: java, search, linear-search

so I'm trying to write a linear search which could be used for most non-primitive data types.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public static <T> boolean search(Comparable<T> key, T[] array) {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i].equals(key)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way this could be done, or a neater way. **N.B.** I am just looking to use a linear search algorithm

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`List#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) for a linear search. Also, there's no need for `Comparable` in this case.

```
public static <T> boolean search(T needle, T[] haystack) {
    return Arrays.asList(haystack).contains(needle);
}
```

Note: `Arrays.asList` returns a `List` view of the array. It won't make a copy.

Comment: Without using an Arrays implementation, would my answer above still be suffice?

Comment: Yes. Though `Comparable` isn't needed. You could alternatively use a `foreach` loop too.

Answer (score -3):

Binary search works amazing! And it's quite simple.

```
public static <T> boolean search(Comparable<T> key, T[] array) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = array.length - 1;
    while (start <= end) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        if (key == array[mid]) {
            return true;
        }
        if (key < array[mid]) {
            end = mid - 1;
        } else {
            start = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please include relevant parts in the answer itself instead of dumping a link. Links break over time.

Comment: Got it! Decided to code it up, help OP directly instead.

Comment: I was looking for just a linear search, not another type of search algorithm